# SoapClient fails with - Failed to load external entity

Tags: api, soap

I am trying to run a SOAP request from my client's Mangento website.

Its throwing below error

> 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn\'t load from \'https://swsim.testing.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv50.asmx?wsdl\' : failed to load external entity "https://swsim.testing.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv50.asmx?wsdl"

Here is my code.

```
class Stamps extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline implements \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface{
    .....
    .....
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request){
        $wsdl = 'https://swsim.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv50.asmx?wsdl';
        $client = new SoapClient( $wsdl, array( 'trace' =>  true ) );
    }
}
```

When I  try to use exact same code outside of Magento, It working fine.

In Magento, is any way to restrict to access an external entity for some directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by manually loading the WSDL from local instead of loading from remote URI.

Comment: For me, this is not a proper answer: what if they decide to change WSDL ? You will have to check every morning , or make a CRON to download it ? :( The problem is that _magento\framework\Config\Dom.php_  _validateDoculent() is called, when it should not be... I still don't know why.